# Write a program to trim both leading, trailing and extra whitespace characters from given string in JavaScript without using inbuilt methods?

Tags: javascript, trim

1. First I tried to understand the question as a beginner and tried to build logic to find the solution of the question.
2. After that failing many times to build a proper logic .
3. Then I started to find logic on google.
4. And I get the logic for this question in C language here is the link https://codeforwin.org/2016/04/c-program-to-trim-both-leading-and-trailing-white-spaces-in-string.html
5. But after trying many times I failed to convert C language code to JavaScript code as a beginner I understand that there is a very huge difference between C language and JavaScript language but I tried to implement the logic and finally, I failed.
6. I want my code to print the string after trimming both leading, trailing, and extra whitespace characters.

here is my code-

```
var str = "     Lots of leading space!   ";
var index = 0;
var len = str.length-1;
var i = 0;
var j = 0;

while(str[index] == ' ' || str[index] == '\t' || str[index] == '\n'){
index++;
}

while(str[i + index] != len){
str[i] = str[i + index];
i++;
}

str[i] = len;
i = 0;

index = -1;
while(str[i] != len){
if(str[i] != ' ' && str[i] != '\t' && str[i] != '\n'){
        index = i;
    }

    i++;
}
str[index + 1] = len;
```

Comment: Iterate the second loop backwards using `lastIndex` variable, you'll get the index of the last non-space character, the characters from `index` to `lastIndex` is the desired result.

Comment: I think I'm not allowed to use some methods but i can use methods  which are really necessary but not all methods cuz right now i'm a beginner and I think that indexOf() method is not allowed to use and yeah I think I'm allowed to use split() method @emre-ozgun

Comment: yeah but u can use indexOf() method if u want to show me how solve this problem after that we can figure out if there is any way that we replace it with indexOf() method @emre-ozgun

Comment: thank you @Teemu its second time u r here to help me

Answer (score 3):

In javascript, strings are immutable. You **cannot** "replace" a character by writing something like `str[0] = "A"`.

Since the C snippet you posted mostly relies on changing the string you give it, I think it'll be hard to convert directly.

Maybe it makes more sense to find the indexes of the leading and trailing white space, and then append each of the characters between those points to a new string?

```js
var str = "     Lots of          leading space!   ";
var newStr = "";

var start = 0;
var end = str.length - 1;
var i;

// Find start
while(str[start] == ' ' || str[start] == '\t' || str[start] == '\n'){
  start++;
}

// Find end
while(str[end] == ' ' || str[end] == '\t' || str[end] == '\n'){
  end--;
}

// Build new string
i = start;
while (i <= end) {
  newStr += str[i];
  i++;
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(newStr));
```

Edit: To remove extra whitespace, you can modify the way you build your new string.

```js
var str = "     Lots of          leading space!   ";
var newStr = "";

var start = 0;
var end = str.length - 1;
var i;

function isWhiteSpace(char) {
  return char == ' ' || char == '\t' || char == '\n';
}

// Find start
while(isWhiteSpace(str[start])) {
  start++;
}

// Find end
while(isWhiteSpace(str[end])) {
  end--;
}

// Build new string
i = start;
while (i <= end) {
  var char = str[i++];
  
  if (
    isWhiteSpace(char) &&
    isWhiteSpace(newStr[newStr.length - 1])
  ) continue;
  
  newStr += char;
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(newStr));
```

Comment: Note: It is unclear to me if any "double spaces" between words should also be cleaned. This snippet does _not_ touch those. I'll assume you'll be able to figure it out now you know strings can't be mutated in place. If not, let me know. I can edit the answer and include it.

Comment: yes, i  also want to remove extra spaces between words I mean double spaces @user3297291 and thank you for ur help

Comment: You're welcome. I added a snippet that handles double spaces. It only adds whitespace characters to the new string if its current last character is _not_ a whitespace.

Comment: sorry for  disturbing you again but I'm having trouble understanding the if condition please help me to understand how this is exactly working @user3297291

Comment: It can be read as "if the current character is a white space, *and* the last character we added to our string is *also* a whitespace, do not add the current character".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239941/discussion-between-alpha-momin-and-user3297291).